# PHP Insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

So i have php code to insert form data in a table. Here's the code:

```
$link = @mysql_connect("***", "***", "****");
if (!$link) {
 echo "save_failed";
 return; 
}
mysql_select_db("***", $link);

$sql="INSERT INTO Conference (`First Name`, `Last Name`)
VALUES ('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]')";

mysql_close($link);
```

The *** are replaced with the actual values in the real code, obviously. But is there anything wrong with the above code? I tried to run it, it didn't have any errors with connection but it also didn't insert anything. Here's is what my mysql table looks like:
[image: Mysql table]

Also, I need the table to have an auto incremented number so that each entry is unique with it's own index value. Any ideas on either problem? Thanks

Comment: What does your generated SQL look like? If you echo out `$sql`, does it work when you run it in the database?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: This example has a **severe** [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php) that should be patched immediately. You should not ever insert `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into your query.

Comment: @DCoder is right - if you don't use PDO, you will get pwned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't executed the query, which should be done as it follows:

```
mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

Also, please consider using [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or even better [`PDO`](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as the `mysql` package is deprecated (see the red box), i.e. [`mysql_query()`](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: wow i feel really stupid. Okay that worked perfectly, thank you. One more thing, is there any way to get that auto-incremented id number?

Comment: From what I see on your screenshot, you don't have an `id` column in your table. Also it would be a good practice to replace space with an underscore.

Comment: Yah I tried putting an ID column but there is no setting to make it auto increment.

Comment: Yes, there is. Have a good look in all the options to a field ;-)